# Will I be able to change the region on my HTC desire S?

Tags: htc-desire-s, localization

The RUU of the HTCdev cannot install to my Htc desire S. It always says that I need the correct RUU version and my region is SEA_WWE.

Is there any way to install the RUU without changing my region? or how do I change the region to make my phone compatible?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one RUU available for Desire S in htcdev website which should work on all HTC Desire S.